# The content on the top half of a website overlaps with the bottom half on mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, overlap

I'm playing around with an old website design of mine, and I've noticed that the content is overlapping on mobile devices.

I've uploaded the mock version of the site here:
http://aestheticinsights.breezybuy.com

The site has a header section, scrolling slider section, and a tabbed information section. On desktops, everything looks fine.

But if you view it on a mobile device, the slider section is overlapping with the tabs (I've been testing on mobiletest.me).

I can't figure out what's causing the issue. I'm not sure which part of the code to share, but I can copy whatever needs to be looked at.

Thanks for any help I can get!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by a height being set on the #show-box  element. This height isn't enough for the content that is contained within it when the screen is smaller.

Comment: I can't believe it was something that simple! Thanks for the answer - that fixed it!